# Safari Intelligent Tracking Prevention blocks Google Analytics in iframe settings

Tags: google-analytics, mobile-safari, google-analytics-4

I have my application running in iframe `https://iframe-domain.com` embedded in the main site `https://parent-domain.com`. With a bit of pain I was able to setup google analytics and GTM to make it work. For this I've used the configuration

```
cookie_flags: max-age=7200;secure;samesite=none
```

in Google tag manager. Then it worked in all browsers **except Safari**. I've noticed that safari ITP (Intelligent tracking prevention) is blocking GA (more precisely, it's blocking third-party cookies) because of the cross-origin iframe. This is reproducible in mobile safari, not sure about the desktop.

Is there any workaround? I don't want to miss all my safari users in analytics reports. GA version 4 is used.

Comment: It happens for me in macOS Safari 17.1 as well.