# Sending GA events in an iframe *without* communicating with the parent

Tags: iframe, google-analytics

I've got a problem that's a bit different to usual GA iframe setups.

I have a widget that is to be embedded on other websites in an iframe. We'd like GA analytics events from our own widget, such as load and custom GA events that we send via JavaScript. We don't care about GA for the parent site, and in fact don't want to have to add any custom code there. The parent site may not even use GA itself.

Our GA events are getting sent in Safari when the "Prevent cross-site tracking" checkbox is unchecked—we can see GA `collect` API requests being made. However, when this checkbox is checked, the API requests are no longer made and we don't receive any analytics from the iframe.

It seems like this might be related to third-party cookie issues, but I don't understand why it would affect the POST requests GA makes as well?

My question is: what do we change in order to be able to send GA events from within the iframe, without any communication with the parent? (A lot of solutions talk about forwarding events to the parent frame, but we don't want that—that parent should be able to not have any GA code at all.)

Do we have to create some API endpoint on the same domain as the widget to make fetch requests to, then somehow forward those to GA from the server?

Comment: This is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72982784/safari-intelligent-tracking-prevention-blocks-google-analytics-in-iframe-setting

Comment: I think you have answered your own question, if Safari is blocking a direct connection and you don't want to do it via the parent page. Then a server proxy is the only remaining option.